# What might cause (JSON ERROR: no value for)?

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I have written some code in Kotlin that should retrieve some data for a dictionary app using the JSON Request Object. I can see that the call is made successfully. The website receiving the call shows the data being sent back but I'm not getting anything back in the results object. Logcat is showing this error (E/JSON ERROR: No value for results). I'm not sure where I'm going wrong in extracting the results. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
  val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            { response ->
                try {

                    val resultsObj = response.getJSONObject("results")
                    val result: JSONObject = response.getJSONObject("result")
                    val term = result.getString("term")
                    val definition = result.getString("definition")
                    val partOfSpeech = result.getString("partOfSpeech")
                    val example = result.getString("example")


                } catch (ex: JSONException) {

                    Log.e("JSON ERROR", ex.message!!)
                }

            },
            { error: VolleyError? -> error?.printStackTrace() })
```

The JSON

```
{
"results": {
    "result": {
        "term": "consistent, uniform",
        "definition": "the same throughout in structure or composition",
        "partofspeech": "adj",
        "example": "bituminous coal is often treated as a 
         consistent and homogeneous product" 
              }
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the json format? [Json Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Here with this code it is valid. You had his character end line in the wrong place.

```
{
   "results":{
      "result":{
         "term":"consistent, uniform",
         "definition":"the same throughout in structure or composition",
         "partofspeech":"adj",
         "example":"bituminous coal is often treated as a consistent and homogeneous product"
      }
   }
}
```